# Core2Duo T5870 unable to run 64bit Vmware Guest

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, vmware

I currently own a Core 2 Duo T5870. People said that its a 64 bit processor, and I am able to install and run 64 bit Windows 8.1 on it. But when I try to run Ubuntu 14.05 64 bit on VMware Workstation 11, it says that my hardware is unable to run 64 bit guest OS.

Is there a way to work around this? Even if it runs slow like a snail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [VT-X support for 64 bit guests](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003945) IIRC, and there's no [64 bit support in that processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/37034/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T5870-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)

Comment: thanks, i run the tool in the web u gave and it show not support :( in boot setting also no option to change it, i guess i have to find another way

Comment: @Tj3n you can run 32 bit version of Ubuntu as guest OS if it suits your purpose.

Comment: In most cases this is a better idea.

Comment: im trying to run cryptdb for my project that it required ubuntu 64 bit, thats why i have to ask, i figure out that while i cant run it in vmware, i could run it dual boot, require some more extra work but its runable!